# Adding cms function on my existing django site

Tags: django, frameworks, web, content-management-system, django-cms

I just started learning django a while ago and I almost finished building my first django site. Now I learned about cms and find it would be a cool feature for my site to update and show what's going on with my life. How can I add this feature without starting over a new project with mezzanine. Basically I just want a micro blog on my font-page with basic features like comment.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FeinCMS (http://www.feincms.org/) is pretty easy to integrate into an existing web site.

By just adding a couple of lines in your settings.py and defining a Page model, you would have a working CMS. It doesn't require a lot of "template refactoring". FeinCMS has a basic blogging module (http://www.feincms.org/plugins/).

Django-CMS is a nice one as well (especially the killing front-end editing feature), but is less configurable and flexible than FeinCMS. Django-CMS has a lot of plugins too.

Comment: thank you for replaying! just tried feincms and it works good.